# Program-o doesn't recognise my name

Tags: php, api, aiml, program-o

I use these aiml in program-o:

```
 <category><pattern>CALL ME *</pattern>
<template><think><set name="personality">average</set></think> <random>  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hi,</li>
  <li>Hi there</li>
  <li>What's up,</li>
  <li>How are you,</li>
  <li>Glad to see you,</li>
  <li>Nice to meet you,</li>
  <li>Glad to know you,</li>
  <li>How can I help you,</li>
  <li>How are you doing,</li>
  <li>OK I will call you</li>
  <li>Pleased to meet you,</li>
  <li>It's good to see you,</li>
  <li>It's good to meet you,</li>
  <li>That's a very nice name,</li>
  <li>I am very pleased to meet you</li>
  <li>I am always glad to make new friends,</li>
  <li>I'm pleased to introduce myself to you,</li>
  <li>It is a pleasure to introduce myself to you, </li>
</random> <set name="name"><formal><star/></formal></set>.</template>
</category>

<category><pattern>WHAT IS MY NAME</pattern>
<template><srai>my name</srai></template>
</category>

<category><pattern>MY NAME</pattern>
<template>
<condition name="name">  
<li value="OM">I'd like to know your name.</li>  
<li value="JUDGE">I know you as Judge.</li>  
<li value="*">You said your name is <get name="name"/>?</li>  
<li>I don't know.  What is your name?</li></condition>
</template>
</category>
```

If I write **Call me John**  then the chat bot answer with this: **Pleased to meet you, John** . If I ask the chatbot **What is my name?** then the chatbot answer: You said your name is Seeker?

What is the problem?

Comment: Is there PHP you forgot to include?

Comment: I didn't touch the php. I only installed the program-o and uploaded the aiml files and lastly I tested the program-o if it works but the chatbot doesn't save my name.

Comment: Well this is just XML someone familiar with `program-o` is going to need to help you with this I guess. You might want to tag that and/or add it back to the title.

Comment: I tried put programo and program-o tags but stackoverflow says I must have 1500 reputition if I want add new tags, because those two tags doesn't exists in default tags.

Comment: I've created a tag for it, and put the term back in your title. I'm not familiar with this though so can't help you. From other questions it looks like there is javascript also involved, I dont know if that is included or not.

Comment: Thank you for the program-o tag. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know now what is the problem.
With aiml and program-o there is no problem.
I used https://byet.host/ first and after I tried https://www.hostinger.co.uk and program-o doesn't work properly. So I tried with localhost, with xampp and there worked perfectly.
I didn't thought that free hostings doesn't support the program-o on 100%.